# Javascript Reference Confusion

Tags: javascript

The class gets instantiated and stored in a variable. The reference of the variable is used to change 'prop' to 'change'. The reference is passed and stored in another variable and logged out. Aaaaaaaaaannnndddd I don't get it.

```
function ctrl () {

  function Klasse () {
      this.prop = 'prop';
  }

  var _klasse = new Klasse();

  return {
      get: function () {
          console.log('get', _klasse);
          return _klasse
      },
      change: function () {
          _klasse.prop = 'changed';
          console.log('change', _klasse);
      },
      reset : function () {
          _klasse = new Klasse();            
      }
  }
}

ctrl().change();
var _klasseReferenz = ctrl().get();

// Why is _klasseReferenz.prop !== 'changed' ????
console.log('referenz ', _klasseReferenz);
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lfg85x96/1/

Comment: With every call of `ctrl()` you create a new instande of `Klasse`. So the changes executed on the first call to not affect the instance created in the second call.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lfg85x96/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every time you call `ctrl` it will create new `Klasse` instance. You should change this to:

```
var ctrlInstance = new ctrl();
ctrlInstance.change();
var _klasseReferenz = ctrlInstance.get();

console.log('referenz ', _klasseReferenz);
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3o81yhbe/)

Comment: Might be better to use a different name for the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `ctrl()` you create a new instance of `_klass` local to that closure. You need to save the reference call, and call get and update on that.

```
var reference = ctrl();
reference.change();
var _klasseReferenz = reference.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

ctrl().change();   --> you are just calling function seperately (not saving reference call)

var _klasseReferenz = ctrl().get(); --> In this like you are creating an object.

// Why is _klasseReferenz.prop !== 'changed' ????
console.log('referenz ', _klasseReferenz);

In first line you are only calling function and there is no reference, from the second line
onward you have created an object and start refrencing it.

Use below line of code to understand

```
var ctl = new ctrl();
ctl.change();
console.log('NowRefrenceWorking ', ctl.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating to references of the ctrl function.
Instead of ctrl().change() and ctrl().get() just assign a new ctrl instance to a variable

```
var _ctrl = new ctrl();
ctrl.change();
ctrl.get();
```